# Can't access sqlite table with fts4 - java.sqlite.SQLException: no such table:?

Tags: java, database, sqlite, jdbc, fts4

> java.sqlite.SQLException: no such table: student

I get this error message when I try to show data in my JTable from my fts4 table in sqlite database. I know my code is good because it works on ordinary sqlite table. 
But I can't access "Virtual tables using fts4". I can access my database but this virtual table with fts4 is giving me a headache.
I use Firefox add-on SQLite Manager to create fts4 tables with this query:

> CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE student USING fts4 (id, first_name, last_name);

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class TestGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    SqliteConnection sc = new SqliteConnection();

    public TestGUI() {
        initComponents();
        con = SqliteConnection.ConnectSqlite();
        UpdateTable();

    }

    public void UpdateTable(){

        try {
            String sql = "SELECT * from student";
            pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            studentTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

Do I need to use some different driver for this? I used this code to connect to sqlite database:

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SqliteConnection {
    public Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public static Connection ConnectSqlite(){
        try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Documents and Settings\\Zoran Davidovic\\My Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Test\\baza1.sqlite");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection successful!");
        return conn;
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!");
            return null;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Obviously, the database file that you're actually opening does not have this table.

Comment: It does, but this table is no ordinary tabel, it is virtual table that uses fts4.

Comment: What evidence do you have for that? The error message proves otherwise.

Comment: What evidence do you need?

Comment: The error message is evidence that the table is not there. I was asking you why you think that the table is there.

Comment: Because I created the table in with SQLite menager in my sqlite database.

Comment: I can read, update, search etc. from other normal tables just fine.

Comment: So I guess the DB changed with SQLite Manager is not the same DB opened by the program.